# Querying by id or friendly URL - Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm working on a REST API with laravel.

I have a blogs table

```
Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->longtext('body');
    $table->string('friendly_url');
});
```

I have a my route set up for the show controller that will display the blog searched by id

Route

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'BlogController@show');
```

Controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $blog = Blog::find($id);
        if (!$blog) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => '404 Not Found'
            ], 400);
        }
    return response()->json($blog, 200);
}
```

So by accessing

```
/api/blog/1
```

I get

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title of my blog",
    "body": "conteudo do meu blog",
    "friendly_url": "title-of-my-blog",
    "category_id": 2
}
```

but I want to check the blog also by the friendly URL

```
/api/blog/{friendly-url} OR {id}

/api/blog/title-of-my-blog
```

and get the same result

I would like to know the best practice to do this, someone to help?

Comment: I did not say I had a problem, I asked him what he wanted to do.

Comment: the problem is that route receives only one parameter, being id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually like the idea of using the id or the "slug"/"friendly url" with the same link structure but can't you just do:

```
$blog = Blog::where('id', $id)->orWhere('friendly_url', $id)->first();
```

I'd recommend just using the friendly url.  You have that field for a reason, although it should be unique in the database.

Comment: Thank you very much